# How to make your Javascript run conditionally, depending on the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I want a piece of Javascript to run if the browser is not IE or it is IE 9+. If the browser is IE8 or a lower version, another piece of Javascript should run.

I tried to use [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if (!IE)|(gte IE 9)]>
    <script type="text/javascript"> /* code 1 */ </script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (lt IE 9)]>
    <script type="text/javascript"> /* code 2 */ </script>
<![endif]-->
```

But IE6 and IE7 still were executing **code 1**. And Firefox was executing **code 2**...

No jQuery, please.

**Edit:** Actually, my conditional expression was wrong. But still went with the feature detection proposed in the chosen answer.

Comment: It is generally much, much better to do feature detection than browser detection.  So, if you describe what feature you want to use in IE9 and other browsers, but not in IE8 and below, then you can use a run-time feature detection which generally is more accurate than browser detection.

Comment: I want to use document.getElementByClass(), which is only available in IE8+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds like you're just trying to decide if you can use `document.getElementsByClassName()`.  If that's the case, you can use feature detection like this:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
    // code here that uses getElementsByClassName
} else {
    // code here that doesn't use getElementsByClassName
}
```

---

It may be cleaner to just install a polyfill so that you can use it in older versions of IE without having to check first.  There are a number of them available you can find with a Google search.  Here's [one](https://gist.github.com/2299607):

```
// Add a getElementsByClassName function if the browser doesn't have one
// Limitation: only works with one class name
// Copyright: Eike Send http://eike.se/nd
// License: MIT License

if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
  document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
    var d = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
    if (d.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
      return d.querySelectorAll("." + search);
    }
    if (d.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
      pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
      elements = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
      while ((i = elements.iterateNext())) {
        results.push(i);
      }
    } else {
      elements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
      pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but in your `IE6, IE7` section, what happens if `search` contains quotation marks (")? Do they have injection risk and should be encoded first, or what happens?

Comment: @daddy7860 - This isn't a function that would normally be call with user content as the `search` argument.  This is intended for a programming function where it's called by your code and passed arguments from your code, not something from the user.  The `search` parameter does have to follow appropriate rules in order to work properly.  But, I would think that the downside to passing something wrong for the `search` parameter is that is most likely that it just won't find what you want.  Hopefully, you also realize that the IE6, IE7 branch should no longer be needed either.

Comment: Ah, okay. Makes sense. Glad you're still around, and thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this best by a check within javascript instead of one in HTML. In JS you have the property `navigator.userAgent` which returns a unique string for each browser (and even IE in its different compatibility versions). So I would suggest to execute the whole JS block in all browsers and simply add something like this add the top of it:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 9.0') !== -1)
{
  // call IE9 specific method
}
else
{
  // call method for other browsers
}
```

For a more sophisticated approach see this post [navigator.userAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986993/navigator-useragent)

Comment: This doesn't handle IE 10, 11, 12, 13, etc... and does not implement the logic the OP asked for.  In addition, feature detection is probably a much smarter way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As jfriend00 states feature detection may be a better solution but here is the conditional comments that satisfy your requirements.

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]> -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> alert('ie9+ and not ie') </script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript"> alert(' < ie9') </script>
<![endif]-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/szF4J/1/